# SSHD configuración para que no se desconecte

Tags: linux, servidor, debian, ssh, putty

tengo un servidor con linux el cual me conecto desde una máquina windows con putty, en el archivo de configuración del servidor linux tengo lo siguiente :

```
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 1800 
ClientAliveCountMax 3
KeepAlive yes
```

En la configuracíon del Putty -> apartado "Data" , tengo activada la opción **Enable TCP keepalives**

El problema que tengo es que al minuto se me desconecta la sesión del SSH y quiero que no sea asi.

Además el comando de putty lo lanzo desde un archivo .bat tal como este, con lo que deberia saber la forma de pasarle dicho parametro para que me funcione.

**start putty.exe 217.XXX.XXX -l user1 -pw passwordsecreto**

Se os ocurre como pasarle a este comando el parametro "Seconds between keepalives"

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Putty, en `Seconds between keepalives` debes tener un valor mayor que cero y -en tu caso- menor que 60.

Comment: Lo tengo en 0 ya que en el comentario pone (0 to turn off)

Comment: Si, precisamente no lo necesitas `off`.

Comment: Gracias @Sal con tu respuesta lo he solucionado, ahora me falta ver como puedo ponerlo en un fichero .bat ya que ejecuto putty.exe desde allí. gracias